# Installing Symfony 2 on Windows

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install Symfony 2 on Windows 8.1.
I am using wampp server as my localhost.

First of all I used this command to get symfony file downloaded:

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

Than I used:

```
php symfony
```

After that I created a project:

```
php symfony new my_project
```

Than I used this command to run:

```
php app/console server:run
```

It successfully run but when I visit: http://localhost:8000/ . It opens a symphony page with this error:

```
 No route found for "GET /"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception:

    ResourceNotFoundException »

[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /"  +
[1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:   +
Logs  -
1 error

    ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at D:\Coding\www\my_project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 159
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".

Stack Trace (Plain Text)  +
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normall message as after instalation of default version of symfony2 it does not have any routes defined.

First of all try http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/ instead of http://localhost:8000/.

You can also create a controller with a default route to be able to check if everything is working fine.

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/MainController.php

// ...
class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function homepageAction()
    {
die ("Everythig works fine");
        return true;
    }
}
```

In addition this may be because your demo route is equal to /app/example or something like that. Go to DefaultController in your AppBundle and change @Route parameter to single slash /

https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Can you explain how its routes work? And where is its route located?

Comment: View /src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php. There you should have /**    * @Route("/app/example", name="homepage")     */ change it into /**    * @Route("/", name="homepage")     */ . You will find routing manual in cookbook link above.

Comment: Could you please give a try localhost:8000/app_dev.php/app/example ?

Comment: Than installation went ok and everything is working fine. You can start developing your example page

Comment: So basically its routes works using php annotations:
/**
     * @Route("/app/example", name="homepage")
     */

Comment: How can I make my url like this: http://localhost:8000/ which will say Welcome to the homepage

Comment: Edit /src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php and edit the route to .@Route("/", name="homepage")